# Javascript how to get length of an object inside an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object inside an object which and I want to get its length. I tried with `Object.keys(obj).length` but it shows the length of the parent object I want also to get the length of the child object.

Here's the code I tried.

```js
let data = {
'data': {
  '0x': {
    0: { 
      0: 'test1', 
      330: 'test2'
    }
  }
 }
};

 let hideCtrls = false;
 if(Object.keys(data.data).length == 1){
    let objIn = Object.values(data.data);
    if(Object.values(objIn)[0] == 1) {
      hideCtrls = true;
     } else {
       hideCtrls = false;
     }
  };

console.log(hideCtrls);
```

I want to check the length of `data` inside data, if it's length is 1 I want to check the length of the values inside the first object (in this case it is `0x`). If the length the child object is also 1 I want to set `hideCtrls` to true.

I want to get the length of the this last object `0: { 0: 'test1', 330: 'test2'  }`. Here we have two key value pairs inside so it should return false, if it has only one key value pair it should return true.

**NOTE: The keys are dynamic**

Comment: Voting to close for clarity, David's answer gives you the logic to follow to achieve your goals, but your constraints are vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = {
 data: { '0x': { 0: { 0: 'test1', 330: 'test2' } } }
}

function hideCtrls(){
 if(Object.keys(data['data'][Object.keys(data.data)[0]]['0']).length === 1) return true
 else return false
}

console.log(hideCtrls())
```

Comment: Can be optimized with `return Object.keys(data['data'][Object.keys(data.data)[0]]['0']).length === 1`

Answer (score 1):

`Object.values` returns an array. If you want the child object, you want to immediately index into it. In general, you can use these two helper functions. You just have to nest enough times to get to the object you care about:

```
let hasOneChild = (x) => Object.keys(x).length === 1;
let getOnlyChild = (x) => Object.values(x)[0];

let hideCtrls = false;
if(hasOneChild(data.data)){
    let x = getOnlyChild(data.data)
    if(hasOneChild(x)) {
        let y = getOnlyChild(x);
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Maybe strict equality (`===`) will be better. Even though it won't make a difference here, it is good practice.

Comment: No it should display false because it has two child objects but it returns true. 
https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/jOYKjPy?editors=1111

Comment: @pilchard remove the second value `330: 'test2'` you still get false, but is should be true. because `0:` has only one child key value pair

Comment: @Viira are you trying to make it work for arbitrarily nested objects? I assumed from your example that you only had to deal with two layers of nesting (`0x` in this case). `0x` only has one child object.

Comment: sorry if I made it unclear for you, I want to get the length of the this last object `0: { 0: 'test1', 330: 'test2'  }`. Here we have two key value pairs inside so it should return false, if it has only one key value pair it should return true

Answer (score 0):

[Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) at least allows you to avoid the nightmare of a chained, computed accessor string. Here with a helper function for `objectLength`.

```js
const objectLength = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).length;

const data = { data: { '0x': { 0: { 0: 'test1', 330: 'test2' } } } }

const parent = data.data;
const [{ 0: child }] = Object.values(parent);

const hideCtrls = (objectLength(parent) === 1 && objectLength(child) === 1);

console.log(hideCtrls)
```